# Power BI: How to show the number of Items created per Shift per Day

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to show the Number of Items that were created during a day and additionally differentiate how many of these items were created during which shift. There are three shifts and my Table has one row per Item with the creation time in one column (datetime).

My idea was to create three measures, one per shift. These should count the row, if the time corresponds to the shift. But i dont realy know how to do that. I tried: `Morning shift =  CALCULATE(COUNT('Item'[ID]), HOUR('Item'[CTS]) >= 6 && HOUR('Item'[PR_CTS] < 14))`, but the graph doesn´t show anything.

(If this would work, i then would try to use a "line and stacked column chart" with Date on the x-axis, the total count as line and the three shifts in "column y-axis".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a column (can be a calculated column):

```
Shift = 
  VAR shiftHour = HOUR('Item'[CTS])
  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(), 
      shiftHour >= 6 && shiftHour < 14, "Morning",
      shiftHour >= 14 && shiftHour < 22, "Afternoon",
      "Night")
```

Something like this, then you can either use the automatic measures that powerBI gives you or create your very simple COUNT measure. And use the shift column in the categories of your stacked chart.